# Get specific data from php repository

Tags: php

My problem: I've been asked to get specific data from a list of books in a repository and give the user the option to show only English language books. So, I've tried to run it through a function using get and it didn't work. Is there an easy way to pull specific data from a repository?

Comment: post your code what you have tried.

Comment: It's not clear and please provide some code ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following interfaces:

- `Repository` - loads, inserts, updates and deletes entities
- `Selector` - finds entities based on filters, in a repository
- `Filter` - encapsulates the filtering logic

My `Repository` is database agnostic; in fact it doesn't specify any persistence; it could be anything: SQL database, xml file, remote service, an alien from outer space etc.
    For searching capabilities, the `Repository` constructs an `Selector` which can be filtered, `LIMIT`-ed, sorted and counted. In the end, the selector fetches one or more `Entities` from the persistence.

Here is some sample code:

```php
<?php

interface Repository
{
    public function addEntity(Entity $entity);

    public function updateEntity(Entity $entity);

    public function removeEntity(Entity $entity);

    /**
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function loadEntity($entityId);

    public function factoryEntitySelector():Selector
}


interface Selector extends \Countable
{
    public function count();

    /**
     * @return Entity[]
     */
    public function fetchEntities();

    /**
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function fetchEntity();
    public function limit(...$limit);
    public function filter(Filter $filter);
    public function orderBy($column, $ascending = true);
    public function removeFilter($filterName);
}

interface Filter
{
    public function getFilterName();
}
```

Then, one implementation:

```
class SqlEntityRepository
{
    //...
    public function factoryEntitySelector()
    {
        return new SqlSelector($this);
    }
    //...
}

class SqlSelector implements Selector
{
    //...
    private function adaptFilter(Filter $filter):SqlQueryFilter
    {
         return (new SqlSelectorFilterAdapter())->adaptFilter($filter);
    }
    //...
}

class SqlSelectorFilterAdapter
{
    public function adaptFilter(Filter $filter):SqlQueryFilter
    {
        $concreteClass = (new StringRebaser(
            'Filter\\', 'SqlQueryFilter\\'))
            ->rebase(get_class($filter));

        return new $concreteClass($filter);
    }
}
```

The ideea is that the generic `Selector` uses `Filter` but the implementation `SqlSelector` uses `SqlFilter`; the `SqlSelectorFilterAdapter` adapts a generic `Filter` to a concrete `SqlFilter`.

The client code creates `Filter` objects (that are generic filters) but in the concrete implementation of the selector those filters are transformed in SQL filters.

Other selector implementations, like `InMemorySelector`, transform from `Filter` to `InMemoryFilter` using their specific `InMemorySelectorFilterAdapter`; so, every selector implementation comes with its own filter adapter.

Using this strategy my client code (in the bussines layer) doesn't care about a specific repository or selector implementation.

```
/** @var Repository $repository*/
$selector = $repository->factoryEntitySelector();
$selector->filter(new AttributeEquals('activated', 1))->limit(2)->orderBy('username');
$activatedUserCount = $selector->count(); // evaluates to 100, ignores the limit()
$activatedUsers = $selector->fetchEntities();
```